# Unknown string format for a non-datetime data list

Tags: pandas, list

A lot of the answers are about datetime format data. Mine is about a string of data looks like this: `p01|p02|p03 ...`

After performing split on the string: 
`list(recommend[0].split('|'))`

It seems that the split will create a list of data as `[p01, p02, p03 ... ]` where there's `\n` characters not able to be seen. How can I remove those after splitting the data?

Comment: I don’t see `'\n'` characters before or after...

Comment: @ALollz yes, but the actual data has

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs for string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

You can probably use `lstrip()`, `rstrip()` or `strip()` to remove the leading whitespace, trailing whitespace or both respectively, before splitting your string data with `s.split('|')`.

Comment: I need to strip off the extra spaces for each item, not the whole string, but I think I get some idea from it. Thanks!

Comment: I see, if that's the case, you can use Python's list comprehension. Something like this will work: `[s.strip() for s in strDataList]`